# AFNetworkingReachabilityManager offline at app start when iPhone is connected to wifi

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

This:

```
[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable
```

returns NO at the start of my app when...

1. `[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];` has been called
2. `[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] stopMonitoring];` has **not** been called
3. I'm connected to wifi
4. I'm using the iPhone (not simulator)

How is this possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AFNetworkReachabilityManager` does it's magic asynchronously.  The value of reachable is not valid until some time after startMonitoring is called.  The best way to get that information is via `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:`

Comment: as they say in Italy, gratzi! The only issue is that I make http requests immediately at app launch...i guess I have to set up some callback for those requests and wait! (so that I know if they're online or not)